# Cannot find module (Angular 2)

Tags: angular

I want to create some route with lazy load. But I can't get rid of error

> Cannot find module app/search/search.module

Folder "search" is in the "app" folder, the path is correct. It works without webpack and this trouble starts after webpack configuring.

It works without lazy load.

Where is the problem?

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'search', loadChildren: 'app/search/search.module#SearchModule' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/search' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

search.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SearchComponent } from "./search.component";
import { LocationsComponent } from "./locations/locations.component";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { GoogleMapsService } from "../shared/services/google-maps.service";

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: SearchComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
  declarations: [ SearchComponent, LocationsComponent ],
  providers: [ GoogleMapsService ]
})
export class SearchModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
const routes: Routes = [
        {path: '', component: SearchComponent, children: [
            {path: '**', redirectTo: ''}
        ]}
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should include your `search.module.ts` into the `app.module.ts` and put `SearchModule` in `declarations`.

Or try adding `./` to this `{ path: 'search', loadChildren: 'app/search/search.module#SearchModule' },`. In order to have as a result this:

```
{ path: 'search', loadChildren: './app/search/search.module#SearchModule' },
```